# Using Html.EditorFor to generate a textarea with a specific number of rows and columns

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I know you can use the DataType attribute with the EditorFor html helper to specify that a particular property of a model entity should be displayed as a multi-line input field.

What If I want to specify the number of rows and columns the text area must have?

In the model :

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string HTMLText { get; set; }
```

In the view :

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.HTMLText)
```

Wanted result :

```
<textarea id="HTMLText" rows="10" cols="40">value</textarea>
```

Is there a way to generate this kind of code without using the @Html.Textarea() helper?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure how to set the rows and cols, but you can alter the CSS of those textareas using the `.multi-line` class. This class is added to the textarea when using EditorFor so you can specify the width and height in that class to get your desired dimensions.

```
.multi-line { height:5em; width:5em; }
```

Comment: Using this technique would mean that I'll have to specify a class in the view. I was looking for a way to control this directly from the model.

Comment: @Jason - you would only have to specify it in the view if you did page level CSS.  If you throw it in an external stylesheet then it will not be in the view. I know it doesn't totally answer your question, but just letting you know that it is an option.

Comment: @Lmrini Frozen 's awnser is the better approach instead adding a css class you can use razor to generate the desired attributes.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the attributes size and char equivalent of row and col in Razor/c# ie:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Longtext, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "ctrl-col2 ctrl-col1", @row = "4", @col = "30" } })
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is no longer required on MVC 5 when you have
**@Html.EditorFor** with DataType.MultilineText field.