# How do I specify the columns and rows of a multiline Editor-For in ASP.MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, data-annotations

In ASP.MVC 3, how do I specify the columns and rows for a multiline `EditorFor` (textarea)? I am using `[UIHint("MultilineText")]`, but can't find any documentation on how to add attributes for the text area.

Desired HTML:

```
 <textarea cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Relevant Part of my MVC 3 Model:

```
[UIHint("MultilineText")]
public string Description { get; set; }
```

Relevant Part of my Razor cshtml:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
</div>
```

What I'm getting in View Source:

```
 <div class="editor-field">
     <textarea class="text-box multi-line" id="Description" name="Description"></textarea>
 </div>
```

How do I set rows and columns?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Use TextAreaFor

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "whatever-class", @cols = 80, @rows = 10 })
```

or use style for `multi-line` class.

You could also write [EditorTemplate](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/02/05/mvc-2-editor-template-with-datetime.aspx) for this.

Comment: For anyone reading this: the `@` at `@cols` and `@rows` are unnecessary. I.e. `cols` and `rows` are sufficient.

Answer (score 30):

In ASP.NET MVC 5 you could use the `[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]` attribute. It will render a *TextArea* tag.

```
public class MyModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string MyField { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the view if you need to specify the rows you can do it like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyField, new { htmlAttributes = new { rows = 10 } })
```

Or just use the TextAreaFor with the right overload:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.MyField, 10, 20, null)
```

Comment: Nice to know they made that change. :-)

Comment: Been around since MVC 3 apparently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927003/asp-net-mvc3-textarea-with-html-editorfor

Comment: Thanks for ypur various solutions. They work for me.

Answer (score 9):

This one can also be used with less effort I believe (but I am in MVC 5)

```
@Html.Description(model => model.Story, 20, 50, new { })
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

One option seems to be using CSS to style the textarea

```
.multi-line { height:5em; width:5em; }
```

See [this entry on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021935/creating-multiline-textbox-using-html-helper-function) or [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953000/using-html-editorfor-to-generate-a-textarea-with-a-specific-number-of-rows-and-co)

Amurra's accepted answer seems to imply this class is added automatically when using EditorFor but you'd have to verify this.

EDIT: Confirmed, it does. So yes, if you want to use EditorFor, using this CSS style does what you're looking for.

```
<textarea class="text-box multi-line" id="StoreSearchCriteria_Location" name="StoreSearchCriteria.Location">
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the original poster's question. When using a framework that creates input fields using `EditorFor`, e.g _Telerik ASP.NET MVC_, substituting `TextAreaFor` is not an option. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

in mvc 5

```
              @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Address, 
              new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control", 
                   @placeholder = "Complete Address", @cols = 10, @rows = 10 } })
```

Answer (score 0):

In **.net VB** - you could achieve control over columns and rows with the following in your razor file:

```
@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.generalNotes, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "someClassIfYouWant", .rows = 5,.cols=6}})
```

Answer (score 0):

@Html.TextArea("txtNotes", "", 4, 0, new { @class = "k-textbox", style = "width: 100%; height: 100%;" })